# mid-2009 Macbook Pro not seeing 2nd memory module

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a problem with my mid-2009 Macbook Pro. It has 2x2GB RAM in it, but it only sees one of the 2GB RAM in memory slot: BANK0/DIMM0. I have interchanged the two RAM modules repeatedly and both are working fine in BANK0/DIMM0, but neither does in BANK1/DIMM0. On one occasion after restarting my computer shown 3.75GB RAM available in BANK0/DIMM0 with the 2GB RAM modules in each slot. Another time it was fine, showing 4GB in the two slots. The MAC was tested with another two memory modules, but they also worked only in BANK0/DIMM0, showing a 2GB total memory. I hope it's not a motherboard problem!

I need the 4GB memory for my work, should I just ignore this problem and install a 4GB RAM into my MBP?

Also, my comp won't come back from sleep when I just reopen the lid. The ventilator and the HDD starts, but the screen stays black. No PRAM or SMC reset helped yet...

Any idea what the problem could be??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Memory slots can burn out, according to a local Mac shop, without needing a motherboard replacement.